# Java using resources instead of nodes

Tags: java, sling

I've got a small snippet of code that simply loops through the currentNode
and grabs a imageReference property. Except instead of using nodes can I use
resources instead? I'm really lost on how to go about doing this. Any ideas? What's
slipping me up the most is there's a "NodeIterator" but there isn't a "ResourceIterator".

Node reference:

```
Node currentNode = (Node) context.getAttribute("currentNode");
```

Resource reference:

```
Resource resource = (Resource) context.getAttribute("resource");

NodeIterator chatNode = currentNode.getNodes();

while (chatNode.hasNext()) {
    Node imageNode = chatNode.nextNode();
    if(imageNode.hasProperty("imageReference")){
        printNodeTitle = imageNode.getProperty("imageReference").getString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll reply in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16577189/sling-resource-vs-nodes instead, which is a very similar question.